# Using linq to display dates today and future

Tags: c#, linq

So I'm pretty new when it comes to Linq.
I am used to writing SQL queries so Linq is a little confusing to me.

I'm trying to pull dates dates that are from today onward.

```
public List<Trails> GetTrails()
    {
        return _context.Trails.Include(p => p.TrailAttributes).Include(p => p.TrailReservations).ToList();
    }
```

I've tried to do

```
public List<Trails> GetTrails()
    {
        return _context.Trails.Include(p => p.TrailAttributes).Include(p => p.TrailReservations).Where(p => p.TrailReservations >= Datetime.Now).ToList();
    }
```

But then I run into an issue because datetime doesn't work with ICollections

> State Error CS0019 Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ICollection' and 'DateTime'

```
public ICollection<TrailReservations> TrailReservations { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please check the type of p.TrailReservatons, you are trying to compare a Collection and a Date, maybe you need to take the Date from the list of TrailReservations.

Comment: The `TrailReservations` property is a `ICollection<TrailReservations>`, not a `DateTime`, so you cannot compare it to a `DateTime`.  Can you show the definition of the `TrailReservations` type and how it exposes date/time information?

Comment: You probably meant to define you TrailReservervations variable/property as DateTime not ICollection.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that TrailReservations is a collection, not a single property that is a date time. What you're really asking for is "give me all trails that have at least 1 reservation in the future"

Assuming your TrailReservations entity has some sort of DateTime property, (lets call it ReservationTime):

```
return _context.Trails.Include(p => p.TrailAttributes)
                      .Include(p => p.TrailReservations)
                      .Where(p => p.TrailReservations.Any(tr=>tr.ReservationTime >= Datetime.Now))
                      .ToList();
```

While the resulting `Trails` from this query will be ones with upcoming reservations, this query will return ALL reservations for that trail, even if they are in the past.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that using the .Any is how I pulled the datetime